# What is the difference between publish / subscribe and method ? where/when we use method and publish / subscribe?

Tags: meteor

Today I try to work on meteor and getting an issue to get data from the server page..

I try to search it on google and meteor side but there is two way to get data `publish / subscribe` and `Method`

Have a below code, I didn't know  how to write it on meteor server-side and get that data in client-side

```
function (x)
{
var y =2
var z  = y*x
return z;
}
```

Now I want to call this method in client side

Answer (score 0):

With publish/subscribe you keep track on datas collected.
https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html

According to the documentation:

> Methods are remote functions that Meteor clients can invoke with
>   Meteor.call.

So, to answer the last question: to call your function from client side, you have to use "Meteor.call('yourMethodName', optionalCallBacks);"

EDIT:

Ok, as suggested in the comments, here an example, with your function.
In the server side, lets say on a file called "methods.js" or somethings:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.methods({
  myMethod(x) {
    const y = 2;
    const z = y * x;
    return z;
  }
});
```

then in client side, you could call this mehod, like:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', x, (error, result) => {
  // OPTIONAL CALLBACK RESULT
  console.log(error, result);
});
```

Arguments here, are respectivelly, name of the method, variable named x, callback.

Comment: Please provide an example according to OP's code and correct the code formatting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between publish / subscribe and method ? where/when we use method and publish / subscribe?

So if you want a logic you don't need pub/sub. 
Methods are for logic pub/sub for data handling.

**Important note:**
If you need to work with data from meteor's collection on the method you need to take into account this if method is executed on the server side it has access to all data (collections).
If the method is executed on the client side it has access only to published data.

On the other hand, according to your example, you don't need any data, so I'll skip it.

I strongly suggest using validated methods:

https://github.com/meteor/validated-method

Now let's go to examples

Imagine you have a method

```
export const calculate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'logic.calculate', // methods are usually named like this
  validate: new SimpleSchema({ // use SimpleSchema to autovalidate parameters
    x: {
      type: Number
    }
  }).validator(),
  run({ x }) {
    const y = 2;
    return y*x;
  }
});
```

Things to note:
 1. The file should be imported on the server somewhere.
 2. You need to use validation

Now call it on the client

```
Meteor.call('logic.calculate', { x }, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    do something
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Also, you can import the method directly and call it like this:

```
import { calculate } from '../../api/logic/methods';// use real method path here   

calculate.call({ x }, (error, result) => {
     if (error) {
        do something
     }
     console.log(result);
});
```

Note that for validated methods argument is an object

Answer (score 0):

In meteor, we can create a meteor method and can pass data to client side by `Meteor.call('methodName', 'param')` . But in case of async operation we need to use future. Take a look on below example :

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
  foo: function() {
    const future = new Future();
    someAsyncCall(foo, function bar(error, result) {
      if (error) future.throw(error);
      future.return(result);
    });
    // Execution is paused until callback arrives
    const ret = future.wait(); // Wait on future not Future
    return ret;
  }
});
```